# action controller not posting all the variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

Am posting some value through my ASP.NET MVC 5 controller 's action ,  but the only variable which not being posted is the last variable , it is always the last one that is not being posted.

This is the code:

```
transaction = (Transaction) Session["transaction"];
string affilie = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["affilie"];
//db.transactions.Add(transaction);
//db.SaveChanges();
string refer = transaction.orderNumber;
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string data = string.Format("affilie={0} &Devise={1} &Montant={2} &refer={3}",affilie, transaction.currency,transaction.amount,refer);

byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:22962/Payment/getData");
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: last of what ??

Comment: `&refer={3}` (missing `=`)

Comment: OMG that is true , That was a stupid mistake maybe i must Go to sleep and have some rest .  Thank you.

Comment: I added the = sign but it did not post.it is always  the last param that is not posted.

Comment: Your method is called getData but you are using POST. Are you posting that 'data' or are you using it as a query string?